# Prove that $\eta - \omega \notin \mathbb{Q}$ where $\omega$ and $\eta$ are two differents n-th primitive roots $\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, arithmetic, primitive-roots

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be a natural number, and be $\omega$ and $\eta$ two differents n-th primitive roots in $\mathbb{C}$.

Prove that $\eta - \omega \notin \mathbb{Q}$

My attempt was to follow the false line of the following :

If i'd to prove that $\sqrt-2 - \sqrt-5 \notin \mathbb{Q}$, i'd try something by contradiction like : $$\sqrt-2 - \sqrt-5 = \alpha, \alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$$

$$\sqrt-2 = \sqrt-5 + \alpha$$ 
$$ -2 = \alpha^{2} + 2\alpha\sqrt-5 -5$$

But then $-2,\alpha^{2},-5 \in \mathbb{Q}$ which leads to $\sqrt-5 \in \mathbb{Q}$,false.

So here i'd like to re-write $$\eta = \omega + \alpha , \alpha \in \mathbb{Q} $$

And raise to the n-th power sothat $\eta \in \mathbb{Q}$, but then i'm unable to find some contradiction due to the difficulties in seeing the terms of the newton binomial $(\omega + \alpha )^{n}$.

Is this the right approach ?

Any help or tip would be appreciated,

Thanks a lot

Comment: n-th primitive roots in ℂ, to be proper complex roots, let's say n > 2 ?

Comment: $-1$ is the only primitive root of order $2$, so the case $n=2$ is vacuously true. Anyway, what do you know about the minimal polynomials of the primitive roots? There is a sleek argument using the piece of information that all primitive roots of unity of a **given** order share the same minimal polynomial. But I dare not use that, if you haven't heard about cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, heard about a lot of cyclotomic polynomials, i'd rather not use Galois theory

Comment: To give you a taste, the primitive roots of unity of order four are zeros of the polynomial $p(x)=x^2+1$. More precisely $p(x)=(x-\omega)(x-\eta)$ where $\omega$ and $\eta$ are the two primitive roots. Now, if $\eta=\omega+q$ for some rational number $q$, this means that $\omega$ is also a zero of the polynomial $f(x)=p(x+q)$ because $$f(\omega)=p(\omega+q)=p(\eta)=0.$$ Furthermore, $f(x)$ obviously also has rational coefficients. Meaning that $\omega$ is a zero of the greates common divisor of $p(x)$ and $f(x)$. But $p(x)$ is irreducible, so....

Comment: But the irreducibility of cyclotomic polynomials is somewhat non-trivial in general. Therefore I needed to ask whether you are familiar with that.

Comment: For irreducibility of the cyclotomic polynomials over $\mathbb{Q}$ could use Eisenstein's criterion, using $\frac{x^{n} -1}{x-1}$, right ? @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Only when the order of those primitive roots is a prime (or a power of a prime), I think. And when $n$ is odd, the various primitve roots of unity of order $n$ have distinct imaginary parts, so their differences are trivially not rational because they are not even real.

Comment: May be we need another idea...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You're right

Comment: If $n\equiv2\pmod4$ then any pair of $n$th roots of unity sharing the same imaginary part automatically has one member of the pair non-primitive. But when $4\mid n$ it can happen that two primitive roots of order $n$ share the same imaginary part. But what to do with those?

Comment: Ok, another possible approach. For $\omega-\eta$ to be rational it has to be real. Implying that $\omega=\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha$ and $\eta=-\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha$ for the same $\alpha$, the obviously must be a rational multiple of $2\pi$ with denominator $n$ and numerator coprime to $n$. Basically the contrapositive is to assume that $\cos\alpha$ can be rational in such a case.

Comment: (cont'd) It can be rational, but it turns out that only when $n=2,3,4$ or $6$. And in all those cases either $\omega$ or $\eta$ is not primitive. Ok?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen going to think about it

Comment: My other idea would be to use the fact that for any natural $n$, $\cos nx$ can be written as a polynomial of degree $n$ in $\cos x$. For example $\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1$, $\cos 3x=4\cos^3x-3\cos x$ etc. **So if $\cos\alpha$ is rational, the same applies to $\cos n\alpha$**

Comment: This means that if there is a counterexample where $n$ has prime factors $p$ other than $2$ or $3$, then there is a counterexample with $n=p$ (or ?). At that point you can either prove the irreducibility of the cyclotomic polynomial using Eisenstein, and use the other idea. Or, you can use the fact that sines have distinct values, or reduce to a case $n=8$, $n=12$, $n=9$ or some such.

Comment: Scores of details to check, but I think it works. Probably something cleaner is out there, but I have consumed a few fingers of Laphroaig already, so may be I should stop. Thanks for listening :-)

Comment: An idea: putting $\;\omega=\eta^k\;$ , you could get a contradiction to the fact that $\;1,\,\eta,\,...\,\eta^{\phi(n)-1}\;$ is a basis for $\;\Bbb Q(\eta)/\Bbb Q\;$ . I haven't checked all the details but it might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $|\eta|=|\omega|=1$ and $\eta\neq\omega$ we have $0<|\eta-\omega|\leq2$, and switching $\eta$ and $\omega$ if necessary gives, without loss of generality, that $0<\eta-\omega\leq2$. Suppose now that $\eta-\omega\in\Bbb{Q}$. Because $\eta$ and $\omega$ are integral over $\Bbb{Z}$, so is $\eta-\omega$ and hence $\eta-\omega\in\Bbb{Z}$. This shows that $\eta-\omega\in\{1,2\}$.

If $\eta-\omega=1$ then $\eta=\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ and $\omega=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$, the two $\pm$-signs being the same. But then one is a primitive third root of unity whereas the other is a primitive sixth root of unity, a contradiction.

If $\eta-\omega=2$ then $\eta=1$ and $\omega=-1$, but then one is a primitive first root of unity whereas the other is a primitive second root of unity, a contradiction.

We conclude that $\eta-\omega\notin\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple :-)

Comment: Just two things that are not entirely clear to me, why $\eta - \omega \in \mathbb{Z}$ ? And why can you remove the absolute value so easily ?

Comment: To the second point; if $\eta-\omega<0$ then $\omega-\eta>0$, and the question is symmetric in $\omega$ and $\eta$.

Comment: To the first point; both $\eta$ and $\omega$ are elements of $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$, hence so is $\eta-\omega$. And $\Bbb{Z}[\zeta_n]\cap\Bbb{Q}=\Bbb{Z}$.